# How to Implement Parent Class Method From Child Class Methods

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, abstract

In the parent class we have an abstract method:

`public abstract void parentMethod();`

and in the children classes a method is defined as such:

```
public void parentMethod()
 {
  System.out.println("this is child class 1")
 }
```

and

```
public void parentMethod()
 {
 System.out.println("this is child class 2")
 }
```

respectively.

How would the implementation of the parent classes be completed?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly, do you want to call the child method from the parent class?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Assuming you have `Parent p = new Child1(); p.parentMethod();`, this will call the Child1's method, and thus print "this is child class 1". That's the principle of polymorphism. Please post all the relevant code, and explain precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet there is no relevant code, I came up with this example on my own

Comment: Yes, but this example is incomplete. There is no class, and you're never instanciating anything, nor calling any method. We don't know what you mean, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet the methods I have defined are within classes. Assume the parent class is called `parent` and the child classes are `child1` and `child2` which `extends` the `parent` class.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you want to achieve, and what your question is. And why do you make us assume what the code is, instead of simply posting it?

Comment: @Rosifr is my answer what you're looking for? See the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call children methods from a parent class. Consider reversing the hierarchy (making the parent the child class instead) or make the method part of an external handler that processes objects of the class. Can you provide a sample code then I can advise you further?

**Edit:**

Here I'm assuming you mean you want to call the child method using a parent container. Doing this it would seem like you're having a parent object but it would call the child method.

```
abstract class Parent 
{
     abstract public void parentMethod();
}

class ChildClass extends Parent
{
    @Override
    public void parentMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
 }
```

And then you just `Parent child = new ChildClass();` and `child.parentMethod();` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: My mistake, see my edits.

Comment: `Parent child = new ChildClass();` and `child.parentMethod();` in the child class ?

Comment: @Rosifr You call the child.parentMethod() where you want to execute the code or the method of the class. Most likely the static void Main method or wherever but outside the class

Comment: Should it be `Parent child = new child();` not `Parent child = new childClass();`?

Comment: @Rosifr It should be what you called the child class, in my example I called the child class `childClass` but if you called the child class `child` then that would be correct, just don't name your variable the same as the class because it can give you an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would using `this.displayOptions();` instead of declaring `child` work?

Comment: @Rosifr my pleasure. Glad to be of assistance. Inside the child class? It should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want different impl for the methods of the children your ood is off.

Your parent class should be an interface defining a method to be implemented on the children.

You should then access the method in the children via this